# iOS frameworks not listing in my XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

I have upgraded my XCode to latest version. While I am trying to add new frameworks to my project from "Link Binary with Libraries" option, it is not listing some frameworks.(say, storekit). Please help me to solve the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi All,

Issue got fixed. I changed the Base SDK to iOS 4.3. It was Mac OS X 10.6 in Build Settings.

Thank you.

Comment: You should write up your answer as an answer and then mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed. I changed the Base SDK to iOS 4.3. It was Mac OS X 10.6 in Build Settings.